# Implementing Taylor Series for sine and cosine in C

Tags: c, trigonometry, taylor-series

I've been following the guide my prof gave us, but I just can't find where I went wrong.  I've also been going through some other questions about implementing the Taylor Series in C.

[image]

Just assume that RaiseTo(raise a number to the power of x) is there.

```
double factorial (int n)
{
    int fact = 1,
    flag;

   for (flag = 1; flag <= n; flag++)
   {
        fact *= flag;
   }

   return flag;
}

double sine (double rad)
{

int flag_2,
    plusOrMinus2 = 0; //1 for plus, 0 for minus 
double sin, 
    val2 = rad,
    radRaisedToX2,
    terms;

terms = NUMBER_OF_TERMS; //10 terms

    for (flag_2 = 1; flag_2 <= 2 * terms; flag_2 += 2)
    {
        radRaisedToX2 = RaiseTo(rad, flag_2);   

        if (plusOrMinus2 == 0)
        {
            val2 -=  radRaisedToX2/factorial(flag_2);
            plusOrMinus2++; //Add the next number
        }

        else
        {
            val2 += radRaisedToX2/factorial(flag_2);
            plusOrMinus2--; //Subtract the next number
        }
    }

    sin = val2;
    return sin;
 }

int main()
{
    int degree;
    scanf("%d", &degree);
    double rad, cosx, sinx;
    rad = degree * PI / 180.00;
    //cosx = cosine (rad);
    sinx = sine (rad);
    printf("%lf \n%lf", rad, sinx);
}
```

So during the loop, I get the rad^x, divide it by the factorial of the odd number series starting from 1, then add or subtract it depending on what's needed, but when I run the program, I get outputs way above one, and we all know that the limits of sin(x) are 1 and -1, I'd really like to know where I went wrong so I could improve, sorry if it's a pretty bad question.

Comment: Please show the `factorial` function. If you are obtaining the factorial of `2*terms` then are you aware that `20! = 2432902008176640000`?

Comment: @Weather Okay, edited, and yes I'm aware, our prof told us to solve it with 10 terms, and it only goes as far as 19! for sin but yeah I see that it's a huge number, but I end up with numbers like 157318262.9 for the output when degree is 180, shouldn't it be smaller since the denominator is so huge? God I hate how I can't think properly right now

Comment: You are not even using the erroneous factorial - you returned the wrong variable with `return flag;`, please see my answer. So you divide by a number that is way too small, making the term way too big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything over `12!` is larger than can fit into a 32-bit `int`, so such values will overflow and therefore won't return what you expect.

Instead of computing the full factorial each time, take a look at each term in the sequence relative to the previous one.  For any given term, the next one is `-((x*x)/(flag_2*(flag_2-1))` times the previous one.  So start with a term of `x`, then multiply by that factor for each successive term.

There's also a trick to calculating the result to the precision of a `double` without knowing how many terms you need.  I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: So something like this as my for loop instead of what I have right now? val2 = val2 * (-1.00) * (rad * rad) / (flag_2 * (flag_2 + 1.00));                     sin += val2;

Comment: Actually yeah changing my equation to follow yours made the estimates a lot closer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In the function `factorial` you are doing an `int` multiply before assigned to the `double` return value of the function. Factorials can easily break the `int` range, such as `20! = 2432902008176640000`.

You also returned the wrong variable - the loop counter!

Please change the local variable to `double`, as

```
double factorial (int n)
{
    double fact = 1;
    int flag;

    for (flag = 1; flag <= n; flag++)
    {
        fact *= flag;
    }
    return fact;    // it was the wrong variable, and wrong type
}
```

Also there is not even any need for a factorial calculation. Note that each term of the series multiplies the previous term by `rad` and divides by the term number - with a change of sign.

Comment: Omg thank you so much for pointing that out, I was getting so frustrated since none of the output changed from the last time I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

Another fairly naive, 5-minute approach involves computing a look-up table that contains the first 20 or so factorials, i.e 1! .. 20! This requires very little memory and can increase speed over the 'each-time' computation method. A further optimization can easily be realized in the function that pre-computes the factorials, taking advantage of the relationship each has to the previous one.

An approach that efficiently eliminated branching (if X do Y else do Z) in the loops of the two trig functions would provide yet more speed again.

### C code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int nMaxTerms=20;
double factorials[nMaxTerms];

double factorial(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (double)n * factorial(n - 1.0);
}

void precalcFactorials()
{
    for (int i=1; i<nMaxTerms+1; i++)
    {
        factorials[i-1] = factorial(i);
    }
}

/*
    sin(x) = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - (x^7)/7! .......
*/
double taylorSine(double rads)
{
    double result = rads;

    for (int curTerm=1; curTerm<=(nMaxTerms/2)-1; curTerm++)
    {
        double curTermValue = pow(rads, (curTerm*2)+1);
        curTermValue /= factorials[ curTerm*2 ];
        if (curTerm & 0x01)
            result -= curTermValue;
        else
            result += curTermValue;
    }
    return result;
}

/*
    cos(x) = 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! .......
*/
double taylorCos(double rads)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    for (int curTerm=1; curTerm<=(nMaxTerms/2)-1; curTerm++)
    {
        double curTermValue = pow(rads, (curTerm*2) );
        curTermValue /= factorials[ (curTerm*2) - 1 ];
        if (curTerm & 0x01)
            result -= curTermValue;
        else
            result += curTermValue;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    precalcFactorials();
    printf("Math sin(0.5) = %f\n", sin(0.5));
    printf("taylorSin(0.5) = %f\n", taylorSine(0.5));

    printf("Math cos(0.5) = %f\n", cos(0.5));
    printf("taylorCos(0.5) = %f\n", taylorCos(0.5));

    return 0;
}
```

### output

```
Math sin(0.5) = 0.479426
taylorSin(0.5) = 0.479426
Math cos(0.5) = 0.877583 
taylorCos(0.5) = 0.877583
```

### Javascript

Implemented in javascript, the code produces seemingly identical results (I didn't test very much) to the inbuilt Math library when summing just 7 terms in the sin/cos functions.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 console.log('starting');
 for (var i=1; i<21; i++)
  factorials[i-1] = factorial(i);
 console.log('calculated');
 
 console.log(" Math.cos(0.5) = " + Math.cos(0.5));
 console.log("taylorCos(0.5) = " + taylorCos(0.5));
 console.log('-');
 console.log("  Math.sin(0.5) = " + Math.sin(0.5));
 console.log("taylorSine(0.5) = " + taylorSine(0.5));
}

var factorials = [];

function factorial(n)
{
 if (n==1)
  return 1;
 else
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}

/*
 sin(x) = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - (x^7)/7! .......
*/
function taylorSine(x)
{
 var result = x;
 for (var curTerm=1; curTerm<=7; curTerm++)
 {
  var curTermValue = Math.pow(x, (curTerm*2)+1);
  curTermValue /= factorials[ curTerm*2 ];
  if (curTerm & 0x01)
   result -= curTermValue;
  else
   result += curTermValue;
 }
 return result;
}

/*
 cos(x) = 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! .......
*/
function taylorCos(x)
{
 var result = 1.0;
 for (var curTerm=1; curTerm<=7; curTerm++)
 {
  var curTermValue = Math.pow(x, (curTerm*2));
  curTermValue /= factorials[ (curTerm*2)-1 ];
  if (curTerm & 0x01)
   result -= curTermValue;
  else
   result += curTermValue;
 }
 return result;
}
```