# Implementing a cosine function in C

Tags: c, trigonometry, math.h

I have to implement my own version of the `double cos(double x)` function present in the `<math.h>` library of C.

There are some things that I don't understand about the implementation of this function.

Principally, I have to

receive user input (a `double x`, for example), implement the Taylor series of a cosine upon that `double x`. And return a double number.

I need to compare my implementation with the built-in `double cos(double x)`, and print it out as well.

My function needs to be precise to the level of 1.0e-6 (which is 1 millionth, 7 decimal points after the number)

It seems that I lack the basic understanding of such implementation, since I stumble upon many problems here.

---

my user input is **incorrect**. I applied a double number, and not only it prints out the **wrong number**, it prints out a **random** number every time.

the way I have calculated the cosine value, using the Taylor series of a cosine is probably incorrect as well.

the **built-in** `double cos(double x)` function is having **the same behavior**, printing the **wrong numbers**, and a **random** number every time.

---

I have used the GCC complier, and compiled the files with the following line:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic my_cos.c -lm
```

As you can, every thing about those results is just... wrong:
[image]

---

Here is my my_cos.h file:

```
#define PI 3.1415926535
    
double my_cos(double);
```

---

Here is my my_cos.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "my_cos.h"


double my_cos(double x)
{
  double cos = 1 - ((pow(x,2))/(2)) + ((pow(x,4))/(24)) - ((pow(x,6))/(1*2*3*4*5*6)) + ((pow(x,8))/(1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8)) - ((pow(x,10))/(1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10));
  return cos * ((PI)/(180)); 
}

int main()
{
  double x;
  printf("Please insert a number:");
  scanf("%f", &x);

  printf("Your number is: %f\n", x);

  printf("using my function:");
  printf("%.7f\n", my_cos(x));

  printf("Using C's function:");
  printf("%f\n", cos(x));
   
  return 0;
}
```

This long line `double cos = 1 - ((pow(x,2))/(2)) + ((pow(x,4))/(24)) - ((pow(x,6))/(1*2*3*4*5*6)) + ((pow(x,8))/(1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8)) - ((pow(x,10))/(1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10));`

**is an implementation of the Taylor series of a cosine:**

[image]

This line `return cos * ((PI)/(180));` is supposed to be **a conversion from the degrees form to the radian form**, since the built in function also returns the cosine of an argument in radians.

I would more than appreciate to get advice about how to fix those problems and improve my program.

Comment: At minimum, `%f` is the wrong format specifier for `double`.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest cranking up your warnings.  `gcc` on my system emits the following with sufficient warnings enabled: `warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’`.  It also provides the exact fix (`%lf`).

Comment: Whenever you use a function like `scanf` you should check the return value to see if it converted the number of items you expected and handle the error if it didn't. [Taylor Series in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212158/taylor-series-in-c) or [Implementing Taylor Series for sine and cosine in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808804/implementing-taylor-series-for-sine-and-cosine-in-c) might be helpful. You can search for others too.

Comment: If you look at each term of the series, it can be derived from the previous term. So you can use a loop to calculate each term from the previous, and add it to the sum. One problem with calculating each factorial is that it can overflow an integer type. You don't even need `pow()` or `factorial()` functions.

Comment: Side note: Tailor series calculate cosine already from argument in radians. If you want to convert angle units (e.g. argument in degrees), you should do it *before* evaluating Tailor series.

Comment: If you range restrict the argument in radians, you can get the answer from either the sin or cosine Taylor series in the range [-pi/4, pi/4] and so they should begin to converge quickly with a finite number of terms since |x| < 1.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/995714)

Comment: @SimonGoater For cosine, you need to use the range 0 to π/2.

Comment: @MarkAdler My point was that you can use sine so |x| < 1 for the x in one of the series. For x in [pi/4, pi/2] calculate instead cos(x) = sin(pi/2 - x).

Comment: @SimonGoater Ah, ok. You meant "you can get the answer _for_ either sine or cosine _from_ the Taylor series for _sine_ in the range [-pi/4, pi/4]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the *argument* of cosine to radians, not the *result*. Your routine works fine if you just `return cos;`. Then it matches the `cos()` function pretty well.

As noted in the comments, the calculation can be considerably simplified and sped up by factoring:

```c
double my_cos(double x) {
    x *= x;
    return 1 - x/2 * (1 - x/12 * (1 - x/30 * (1 - x/56 * (1 - x/90))));
}
```

(That, of course, takes the argument in radians. As any self-respecting cosine implementation should. You should do the conversion before calling the function.)

Also as noted in the comments, for accuracy this should be used only in the range of 0 to π/2 (or –π/2 to π/2 if that makes the code simpler), with values outside of that converted into that range with the appropriate sign for the result.

Use `M_PI` from math.h instead of your own defined (and incorrect) constant.

Use `%lf` instead of `%f` when doing a `scanf()` into a `double`.